# Find element with dictionary in Ansible and return value

Tags: python, ansible

i'm trying to value of one yaml file1 with another file2 which has list of dict and if element if file1 matched with key/value of file2 then need to use value of file1 need to use as a key of file2 and return value of it...

not sure how we can leverage "when" condition or might any other way around it...

file1.yaml:

```
  site: CL1
```

file2.yaml:

```
site_int:
  -
    CL1:
      as: 6500X
      int: ethernet1/1
      peer_ip: X.X.X.X/X
    EL1:
      as: 65063
      int: loopback.66
      peer_ip: Y.Y.Y.Y/Y
```

playbook:

```
- name: site_facts
           set_fact:
                   sites: "{{item}}"
           loop: "{{ site_int) }}"


         - name: debug
           debug:
                   msg: "{{sites['site']}}"
           when: "site in sites.key"
```

error:

fatal: [CL1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'site in sites.key()' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (site in sites.key()): 'dict object' has no attribute 'key'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/aws/test_site.yaml':

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
  sites: "{{ site_int|map('dict2items')|
                      map('selectattr', 'key', 'eq', site)|
                      flatten|items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  sites:
    CL1:
      as: 6500X
      int: ethernet1/1
      peer_ip: X.X.X.X/X
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - file1.yaml
    - file2.yaml
  vars:
    sites: "{{ site_int|map('dict2items')|
                        map('selectattr', 'key', 'eq', site)|
                        flatten|items2dict }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          sites.{{ site }}:
            {{ sites[site]|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    sites.CL1:
      as: 6500X
      int: ethernet1/1
      peer_ip: X.X.X.X/X
```